# How to get the day of the week from the day number in Javascript and add as an ID to a button

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to accomplish is get the day of the week using

```
function dayOfWeekAsString(dayIndex) {
    return [
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday",
        "Sunday"
    ][dayIndex];
}
```

Now I need to add the day of week as an ID to a single button so I can call an html anchor in another page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not at all clear what you want to do or what trouble you're having doing it.

Comment: Side note: Rather than re-creating that array every time, I suggest creating it **once** (outside the function) and reusing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, this would look something like:

```
$('#OriginalID').attr('id', dayOfWeekAsString(dayIndex));
```

Then, the OriginalID has effectively been changed to the day of week.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
var days = [
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday",
        "Sunday"
    ];

function dayOfWeekAsString(dayIndex) {
    return days[dayIndex];
}

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].setAttribute('id', dayOfWeekAsString(0));
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

And this button in developer tools:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var day = dayOfWeekAsString(1);
console.log(day)
function dayOfWeekAsString(dayIndex) {
    return [
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday",
        "Sunday"
    ][dayIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var today = d.getDay();
var week =  ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];

function dayOfTheWeek(i) {

    return week[i];
 }

 document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].setAttribute('id', dayOfTheWeek(today));
```

Comment: So then how is the day called using the anchor?

Comment: OK figured ti out...you had a small error ...Sunday HAS to be first else the wrong day gets returned.